# Valid class hierarchy?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, inheritance, tdd, associations

Does the following class hierarchy valid for TDD? I have two related class hierarchies and I need to use one type of Info object in each creator. Do you know common pattern to do this better (maybe with generics)? Is this testable?

```
namespace ClassTest
{
    interface IProjectInfo
    {
        void Info1();
        void Info2();
    }

    class ProjectAInfo : IProjectInfo
    {
        public ProjectAInfo(string projectAData)
        {
            ProjectAData = projectAData;
        }

        public string ProjectAData { get; private set; }

        public void Info1() { }
        public void Info2() { }
    }

    class ProjectBInfo : IProjectInfo
    {
        public ProjectBInfo(string projectBData)
        {
            ProjectBData = projectBData;
        }

        public string ProjectBData { get; private set; }

        public void Info1() { }
        public void Info2() { }
    }

    interface IProjectCreator
    {
        void Create1();
        void Create2();
    }

    class ProjectACreator : IProjectCreator
    {
        public ProjectACreator(ProjectAInfo projectAInfo)
        {
            ProjectAInfo = projectAInfo;
        }

        public ProjectAInfo ProjectAInfo { get; private set; }

        public void Create1() { }
        public void Create2() { }
    }

    class ProjectBCreator : IProjectCreator
    {
        public ProjectBCreator(ProjectBInfo projectBInfo)
        {
            ProjectBInfo = projectBInfo;
        }

        public ProjectBInfo ProjectBInfo { get; private set; }

        public void Create1() { }
        public void Create2() { }
    }
}
```

The info and creator classes share common interfaces. The creator needs info class for its operation.

Thank you!

Comment: Without knowing what this classes actually do it is difficult to give an useful answer. For telling are classes testable or not - write tests for them and you will know without others opinions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't TDD. With TDD, the purpose is to write the test first. If you write your test first, then a class hierarchy will come out of that test and it will be testable. In order to better understand TDD, please take a look at:

[The Rules of TDD by Uncle Bob](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.TheThreeRulesOfTdd)

If your question is just: Is this testable? Yes, it is testable.

Comment: The question itself is about the hierarchies. I mean are these hierarchies acceptable in a valid TDD construct. I need advise from someone who is expert in TDD and can spot design errors in this structure.

Comment: The problem is that we don't know what you are trying to accomplish. When you are writing an application using TDD, at the very least, good design will fall out of it. At least, that has been my experience. What tests have you written?  Why not post your tests with some business use cases and ask if you are approaching it correctly?